# Vue 3 catch error and render another component instead

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I am making a render library for my project with Vue 3 + Vite.

Basically I have a json array of `products` which I pass to special `<Render :products />` component.

This `Render` component reads all json products and converts them into Vue components:

```js
// Render.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Product } from 'bitran';
import { resolveComponent } from 'vue';

const props = defineProps<{ products: Product[] }>();
const products = props.products;
</script>

<template>
    <template v-for="product in products">
        <component :is="resolveComponent(product.type)" :product />
    </template>
</template>
```

Of course errors can occur when rendering json data to component.

**How** can I catch these errors during rendering `<component ... />` and replace them with my own custom `<Error :msg />` component so the rendering process won't stop and the end-user could see, which product caused the problem and why?

For example, I intentionally throw an Error inside my `<Paragraph>` component and would like this `<Paragraph>` component to be converted into `<Error>` component instead:

```js
// Paragraph.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import { Paragraph } from 'bitran';
import { getProductAttrs, useProduct } from '@lib/content/util';
import Render from '@lib/Render.vue';

const block = useProduct<Paragraph>();

throw new Error('This message should be passed to <Error> component!'); // Error here
</script>

<template>
    <p v-bind="getProductAttrs(block)">
        <Render :products="block.content" />
    </p>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to catch errors in `setup()` you could overwrite it and add error handling:

[VUE SFC PLAYGROUND](https://play.vuejs.org/#__PROD__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)

```
<script setup>
import {h} from 'vue';
import Paragraph from './Paragraph.vue';
import ParagraphOK from './ParagraphOK.vue';
import Error from './Error.vue';

const SafeComponent = (props, {slots}) => {
  let component;
  // extract 'is' property
  ({is:component, ...props} = props);
  // overwrite the setup function
  if(component.setup){
    let _setup = component.setup;
    // make a shallow copy of the component to avoid changing original components
    component = {...component, setup: function(props, extra){
      try{
        return _setup.call(component, props, extra ?? {});
      }catch(e){
        // return a render function with rendering the error component
        return () => h(Error, {message: e.message});
      }
    }};
  }
  return h(component, props, slots);
};
</script>

<template>    
        <safe-component :is="Paragraph"><template #header>Header</template>Paragraph</safe-component>
        <safe-component :is="ParagraphOK" product="Product">OK paragraph</safe-component>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works exactly as I want. I have created component `<RenderProducts />` which simply loops through JSON products and for each of them it calls `<RenderProduct />` which contains your code. Now library components with errors are replaced with `<Error />` components and the app is not breaking!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onErrorCaptured` hook to capture the error and the component instance, and get its content and show it, then return false in order to not break the app, the second parameter in the hook callback represents the component instance that's causing the error :

TryRender.vue

```html
<script setup lang="ts">

import { onErrorCaptured } from 'vue';


const componentsCausingErrors = ref([])

onErrorCaptured((_error, instance) => {
    componentsCausingErrors.value.push(instance.$options.name)
    return false
})
</script>

<template>
   {{componentsCausingErrors}}
    <-- other content -->
</template>
```

Note that you should give the component an explicit name using the `defineOptions` macro :

````js
<script setup>
throw new Error('Error in component B');
defineOptions({
  name: 'CompB'
})
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    component B
  </div>
</template>

```
````

Comment: Looks promising. But with this approach it will stop rendering all the blocks and just show an error. I want to convert to `<Error>` only those `<components>` which throw error and let other components render normally. Of course I can use `onErrorCaptured` in everty component in my lib but that would be a huge amount of code duplication... Some kind of "component inheritance" where I can setup some common properties of every component of my lib could solve the problem but I don't know if such a thing exists in Vue.

Comment: The hook can be used once in App.vue, You could also define error as an array that collects the errors and show them as list

Comment: The problem is that I need to know exactly which `product` (or which `<component ...>`) throws an error. In your solution (even if I convert error to an array of errors) it simply says "Yeah, there were 3 errors **somewhere** when rendering products". And I want to put an error message directly in place instead of component which throwed error. Something like `try { <component ... /> } catch { <Error ... />}`. I am new to Vue and maybe missing something...

Comment: Hmm.. maybe I can just create my own `<TryRender ... />` with `onErrorCaptured` hook as a wrapper to `<component is="..." />`...

Comment: based on your last comment I suggested some modifications